# Cannot Get Unwind Segue Working with Modal View Controller Presented Over Current Context

Tags: uimodalpresentationstyle

This is regarding the latest version Xcode 6 and iOS 8.4.

I have a set of three view controllers, which `VC2` & `VC3` are presented modally:

`VC1` -> `VC2` -> `VC3`

Each of the segues are presented with a presentation style of `.OverCurrentContext`. I am using this presentation style because both `VC2` & `VC3` have a `UIVisualEffectView` with a blurred background to let the view underneath subtly show through.

My issue is that the unwind segue that I have created does not unwind neither `VC2` or `VC3` to `VC1` with the presentation style of `.OverCurrentContext`. However, when I change the presentation style back to `.Defatult` it works.

I would really prefer to use `.OverCurrentContext` because having to use `dismissViewController:animated:completion` causes a second unwanted animation of both view controllers when dismissing. I want to be able to dismiss `VC3` and immediately see `VC1` without seeing `VC2` animate it's dismissal between. Also, I do not like using `presentingViewController.presentingViewController.dismissViewController:animated:completion` because it also causes the unwanted animation of dismissing `VC2` after `VC3` has been dismissed.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: I was able to get ```presentingViewController.presentingViewController.dismissViewController:animated:completion``` working correctly, but I am still not sure why I cannot use an unwind segue with the presentation style as ```.OverCurrentContext``` as I feel that the code would be a little cleaner. I was not able to find anything in the documentation that specified unwind segues not being able to be used in conjunction with ```.OverCurrentContext```. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use `presentingViewController.presentingViewController.dismissViewController:animated:completion` from `VC3` to achieve the same effect as using an unwind segue.

However, as noted in my comment, I would still like to know why I had to resort to this rather than being able to use an unwind segue with `.OverCurrentContext`.

Comment: How can I pass a variable if I dismiss a View controller in the way mentioned above?

Comment: @bably The only way that I can think of is to use a delegate pattern to pass information back to the view controller that you need to notify of an event. By using the delegation pattern, you can pass anything that you need to.