# Unwind from OverCurrentContext modal presentation doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, modalviewcontroller, unwind-segue

I am having a problem similar to this:

[Cannot Get Unwind Segue Working with Modal View Controller Presented Over Current Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748605/cannot-get-unwind-segue-working-with-modal-view-controller-presented-over-curren)

I presented a VC modally using OverCurrentContext presentation style following a tutorial. All set in storyboard.

VC1 -> modally overCurrentContext -> VC2

The problem is that Xcode 8 has slightly different options in the Attributes Inspector, no OverCurrentContext option in the Segue, so I had to select the presentation: default in the Segue

[image]

and set the presentation: overCurrentContext in the VC2

[image]

Now, when I try to unwind back to the VC1 I can't, nothing happens and I get stuck in VC2.

I had to add some extra code to the unwind method to make this work.

```
@IBAction func unwindFromAdvancedOptions(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if segue.source as? VC2 != nil {
        segue.source.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But I'd really like to understand why storyboard settings where enough to unwind any other modal presentation styles but OverCurrentContext.

Comment: I may be wrong on this, but I had a problem with it a while back, and found a way around it, then recently I wanted it to unwind again, and this time it worked. I would try updating to the newest version of Xcode and seeing if that helps anything.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response @Sethmr. I am using the last version (8.2.1) already.

Comment: Having the same problem. Took forever to realize the source of it.  Trying to get your workaround to work -- appreciate the lead.  Did you ever get more clarity on why Swift works this way?